# BizTalk 2006 Event Log Warnings - Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dta_MessageFieldValues' with unique index 'IX_MessageFieldValues'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2006

We have been seeing the following 'warnings' in the event log of our BizTalk
machine since upgrading to BTS 2006. They seem to occur
randomly 6 or 8 times per day.

Does anyone know what this means and what needs to be done to clear it up?
we have only one BizTalk server which is running on only one machine.

I am new to BizTalk, so I am unable to find how many tracking host instances running for BizTalk server. Also, can you please let me know that we can configure only one instance for one server/machine?

> **Source:** BAM EventBus Service
>
> **Event:** 5
>
> **Warning Details:**
>   Execute batch error. Exception information: TDDS failed to batch execution
>   of streams. SQLServer: bizprod, Database: BizTalkDTADb.Cannot insert
>   duplicate key row in object 'dta_MessageFieldValues' with unique index
>   'IX_MessageFieldValues'.
>   The statement has been terminated..

Comment: A bit strange that this exact question was asked 9 years ago here http://microsoft.public.biztalk.admin.narkive.com/UUlUmCfv/biztalk-2006-event-log-warnings      Also very strange that you are only just upgrading to BizTalk 2006 when it is out of support.

Answer (score 0):

I see you got a partial answer in your [MSDN Pos](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e1513dce-072b-498f-93f2-f1f9b5779ea9/biztalk-2006-event-log-warnings-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-dtamessagefieldvalues?forum=biztalkgeneral)t

> go to BizTalk Admin Console ,check in Platform Settings -> Hosts, in the list of hosts on the right, confirm that only a single Host has the Tracking column marked as Yes.

As to your other question.  Yes you can run a Single Host Instance on a Single Server.  Although when your server starts to come under a bit of load you may want to consider setting up some more so you can balance the workload better.